# s2Member EOT modification

Tags: php, wordpress

What I am trying to do is when a member “renews” with the modification form is add +1 year to his expiry date regardless on when he renews. The members ALWAYS expire on April 30th so I simply need to add 1 year to make it April 30th 2014, 2015, etc.

So with the following hooks

```
add_action('ws_plugin__s2member_during_paypal_notify_during_subscr_modify', 'update_s2_EOT');
add_action('ws_plugin__s2member_during_paypal_notify_during_subscr_signup_w_update_vars', 'update_s2_EOT');
```

I am doing

```
function update_s2_EOT($vars = array()) {

    $user_id = $vars['user_id'];

    $existing_eot_time = get_user_field('s2member_auto_eot_time', $user_id);

    $new_eot_time = $existing_eot_time;

    update_user_option ($user_id, 's2member_auto_eot_time', $new_eot_time);  
}
```

Obviously this isn’t adding 1 year but it’s just an example. I am able to get the user_id but the EOT variable is ALWAYS blank so after the function runs it sets my EOT for the user to empty.

Why is get_user_field(‘s2member_auto_eot_time’, $user_id); returning blank? (I can confirm that $user_id is set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was never able to get the existing EOT value from any hooks I did some more research and turns out you can do it all from the proform short code.

For example

the rp="" value in the shortcode will append "x" days to the end of the current year so if you just want to add 1 year you can have rp="365".

So if you need a specific day of the month like 30th of April you just need to do some date calculations to figure out how many days until the next 30th of April based on the current EOT set for that user.